# Json data parsing issues in angularJs

Tags: html, angularjs

I am new to angularJs. I am trying to get dJango rest api data from angularJs. Using jsonp method, data is fetching from api (showing in chrome browser sources tab). But it is not showing in html page. Please check below code.

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

var dataController = function ($scope, $http, $window, $sce) {

    var url = 'http://myIpWithPort/ids/?callback=JSON_CALLBACK';
    $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(url);
    $http.jsonp(url,{ jsonpCallbackParam: 'callback' }).then(function (data) {
         $scope.emps = JSON.parse(data.data);
    })
}

myApp.controller('dataController', dataController);
```

```html
<div ng-controller="dataController">
 <div>{{ emps }}</div>
</div>
```

Any one please help me.

Comment: I don't think so you need to do `JSON.parse`.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using `jsonp` method you do not need to parse the data to json again.just assign the values

```
$scope.emps =data.data
```

Comment: Thanks for reply I tried with $scope.emps =data.data also. Still the data is not showing..

Comment: can you create a plnkr

Comment: I dont know about plnkr. please guide me.

Comment: check in above path now.

Comment: sorry for the delay. Power gone in my house. just now i will send

Comment: you need with IP number?

Comment: Are you getting any error on console?  You can look into this link. http://jsfiddle.net/rpragana/d1pmwrjx/